# What is the equivalent of a subject access request for the Schengen Information System (ie, SIS)?

Tags: schengen, europe

How can one learn what records are stored about oneself within the SIS?

Corrollaries (please feel free to edit or critique if these ought to be posted as their own independent questions):

- I'd also like to know the same about the VIS (Visa information system).
- What other similar information sharing networks exist for the broader Europe region?

Answer (score 3):

The EU has some [confusingly-written information](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen-information-system/access-rights-and-data-protection_en) about your rights to access data about you which is stored in the SIS:

> If data about a person are stored, that person has the right to request access to those data and make sure that they are accurate and lawfully entered. If this is not the case, the person has the right to request correction or deletion.

And how to make such a request:

> If you believe your personal information has been misused, needs to be corrected or deleted, you can request access to and rectification of your data. If you are a third-country national you can address your request to the consulate of any Member State. If you are a citizen of a Member State you can either address your request directly to the competent national authority responsible for the issuance of the alert or indirectly to the [national Data Protection Authority](http://ec.europa.eu/justice/data-protection/bodies/authorities/index_en.htm).
>
> [Guidelines](https://secure.edps.europa.eu/EDPSWEB/edps/site/mySite/CSIS) on the national procedures for access requests have been compiled by the national Data Protection Authorities.

If you are an EU citizen or resident, you are probably best off referring to the relevant authorities in your country. If you are lucky, they will provide clear instructions for doing so. For example, the Norwegian police have a page (in English) called “[Do you want to access the Schengen Information System (SIS)?](https://www.politiet.no/en/contact-the-police2/innsyn-og-offentleg-journal/do-you-want-to-access-the-schengen-information-system-sis/)” which contains a form to fill out, an address to mail the form to, and instructions for proving your identity. They also describe the types of information you might be able to find in the SIS:

> The SIS database may contain information about:
>
> - Individuals who are the subject of an arrest warrant or extradition request.
> - Individuals who are wanted by the authorities for some other reason.
> - Individuals who are not entitled to enter or stay in the Schengen area.
> - Individuals who have been reported missing.
> - Lost or stolen items, such as motor vehicles, vehicle registration plates or identity documents.

According to the EU page above, if you are not in Europe, you are supposed to direct your request to the embassy or consulate of any member state. I imagine that most consulates receive relatively few such requests, though, so you might want to email in advance to see what kinds of information they will require in order to process your request, or possibly you may be advised just to contact the relevant national authorities directly.

Comment: Thanks. If you could kindly also address either or both of the corollary questions, I'd be happy to accept this answer.

Comment: For VIS an application should be made directly to the Member State that collected the data. See: [Article 38 (1), EUR-Lex - 32008R0767](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32008R0767#d1e2528-60-1)

Comment: If someone requests access to their profile on SIS, can they contest a travel ban issued by Schengen country? If so, is there a expiry date for contesting such charges?

Comment: @user610620 if you have a new question, you are probably better off [asking a new question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) than hoping someone will see it here.