# Why doesn't my passport show if a foreign country has banned me?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, legal, overstaying

I went to the passport office of my (highly developed Western) country and they said they wouldn't know if a foreign country I had previously overstayed in had banned me or not just by scanning my passport.

Isn't that the point of passports? To contain data and violations on each traveler, and that data is shared between all countries who "access" or scan the passport to make a decision on whether to admit them or not? Do countries not share information about foreign travelers with all other nation states via their passports?

Comment: In addition to the answers's you've been given, passport scanning does not reveal any more information than you can see on the page. It's just a way for computers to access the data more easily.

Comment: How do you know? Cite your source.

Comment: @user610620 ICAO Doc. 9303 Part 1 volume 2, the same standards as for passports. Note that it does indeed note that there is an optional space for e-visa data and such, but it is **not** part of the actual standard yet

Comment: If it were stored in the passport, one could just conveniently lose the passport and be done with the ban. Of course it’s not in the passport. Also remember millions of people have two or more passports.

Comment: Ask Tille Kottman.
https://switzerlandtimes.ch/world/swiss-hacker-23-cracks-the-us-no-fly-list/
I mean, ask them why a country is so jealous of their banned people list to make such a big fuss when someone finds it out ...

Comment: @CMaster that is incorrect.  Some passports, for example, hold digital fingerprints in the chip without making those fingerprints available for visual inspection.

Comment: @EarlGrey Which country is jealous of which country's ban list and making a big fuss about it?

Comment: Note that the passport office of your country is primarily concerned with issuing passports and has little to do with whether or not you're in good standing in any other country (excepting odd situations such as your passport being revoked because you're a fugitive or something). While there are circumstances in which countries may share certain information, there is no global registry of "violations" known to your passport office. The passport office in, say, Canada has nothing to do with and likely no information about whether a Canadian citizen once overstayed their visa in, say, Thailand.

Comment: user610620 - it's fairly trivial to read your passport yourself. The "machine readable" text is also readable to humans, while the RFID chip can be readily accessed by say, most smartphones.

However, according to phoog sometimes there are additional biometrics that are not displayed visually - I'd thought that fingerprints were only encoded when also printed.

Comment: @ZachLipton could you move your comment to an Answer. it's good, sources help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Isn't that the point of passports?

Historically, the point of passports was primarily to prevent people from *leaving* without authorisation. This mechanism can still be used, e.g. when a court forces you to surrender your passport.

In our age of paranoia about immigration, passports are also used the other way around: As a kind of guarantee that you can be expelled if need be. The country issuing the passport thus more-or-less accepts a duty to take you back.

> To contain data and violations on each traveler, and that data is shared between all countries who "access" or scan the passport to make a decision on whether to admit them or not?

The passport, even a recent biometric passport, doesn't contain any data that would be updated after having been issued. The chip mostly contains the data that's visible on the ID page, together with a digital picture and potentially fingerprints. These data are encrypted with a key based on your biographic data. Currently, the only way information is added and shared widely is just through the good old-fashioned stamps you can check yourself.

Scanning the machine-readable area (the strip at the bottom of the ID page) serves two purposes:

- Reading the contents of the chip to detect any alteration of the document and compare the contents with the face and fingerprints of the person trying to cross the border
- Automatically pulling some data (like your name and date of birth) to run searches or even save it in some *national* systems or check if your passport is on some list of invalid document without having to type in the details manually

> Do countries not share information about foreign travelers with all other nation states via their passports?

They mostly don't share information (by any means), with much more limited exceptions than most people seem to assume. It's easy to realize that the US, Iran, Russia, and Venezuela (to name a few) are not going to let each other access up-to-date biometric data about their citizens so you shouldn't expect some sort of worldwide system for that. Even within the Schengen area, where the principle of a central register of entries and exits has been agreed upon and the legal framework has been finalized for years, implementation is a significant challenge.

Note that all this is clearly distinct from information exchange for intelligence purposes. Collaboration between countries on this doesn't mean the data is widely available to all law enforcement officers. That's not how intelligence data is handled.

Comment: Could the **bottom strip of the passport**, when scanned, be the mechanism by which a US border agent would find out that someone was banned from Spain, for example, given that the bottom strip pulls data used to run searches, and save new information, to **national systems**?

Comment: @user610620 That's not what “national” means, that would imply that Spain grants full access to its national systems to the US.

Comment: So the **bottom strip** of the passport does *not* contain information that is shared between countries? The passport holder's home country's passport office will tell the passport holder that **the other strips** above the bottom strip are the only ones their home country would access, and that the bottom strip is the one used by foreign countries, like what you say. So wouldn't you think, if all foreign countries are using the **bottom strip** of the passport, you'd think that there's alot of data inside that bottom strip? Therefore, shared by everyone who's used that bottom strip?

Comment: @user610620 You can read the data that's on the bottom strip (“machine-readable zone”) yourself, it's just a bunch of numbers and letters. It doesn't get updated or contain much data, mostly your name, nationalty, date of birth, document number and expiration data. These data can then be used to decipher the data that's on the chip, which can also be read by anyone (other countries but even yourself with a smartphone) without any data exchange. It *doesn't* include any travel history or any updated data compared to what you submitted when applying for the passport.

Comment: I also have the feeling this has already been explained to you in details. How it works is pretty technical but the bottom line is that no data is being exchanged between countries to make it work and your passport doesn't contain anything beside the information you can read yourself and some biometrics (facial picture, fingerprints). Do you find that difficult to accept?

Comment: how can I read the bottom strip with a smartphone?

Comment: @user610620 Can you pay a little more attention to what's written? You cannot read the bottom strip with a smartphone, you can read the bottom strip with your eyes. What you can read with a smartphone is the contents of the chip if your passport has one.

Comment: Ok typo that's what I'm asking. How can I make my smartphone read **the chip** (not the **bottom strip**)?

Answer (score 44):

No, that is absolutely not the purpose of passports.

The purpose of a passport is to demonstrate that you have the identity and citizenship that you are asserting, and to use that to decide whether to admit you into a country or not. It is also a secure place to store visas that have been issued to you, and proof of when you arrived at (and in some cases, but not all, left) a country. Some countries may use that record in addition to your identity and citizenship to make decisions (not letting you in if you have a stamp from a specific other country) but this is the exception, not the rule. Others may use it to confirm that you are someone who enters countries and then leaves again as planned, increasing their confidence in letting you in. But this is not the purpose of the passport, merely a side effect some countries use in some cases.

Passports do not contain violations, except occasionally when a visa or entrance stamp will be "cancelled" such as by an officer drawing an X over them. Some governments keep lists of violations, and some share those lists with other countries, but it's not universal. When they do share, the mechanism they share with is not your passport, but another form of communication.

The scanning is a quicker way for the officer to enter the information needed to look you up in some system that the officer has access to. This will not be a giant international system shared by all the countries of the world, but something specific to that country and whatever lists it may have of people who have been banned or who are going to get extra scrutiny on each entry. There was a time when the officer typed those things in by hand, but now they can generally swipe instead, or you can put your passport on a scanner and do the whole thing without interacting with a person.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but there is still no resolution to the issue: How then does someone find out they are banned from a country before traveling, without attempting to cross that country's border? Let's use a specific example: Schengen Area (in Europe) and any of its constituent countries.

Comment: That is a different question, and will very much depend on who you think banned you. I suggest asking a separate question: how can I see if I am banned from Schengen after an overstay?

Comment: @user610620 This is called **alert** in the: Schengen Information System (SIS) Article 42 (Right of information) *1. Third-country nationals who are the subject of an **alert** issued in accordance with this Regulation shall be informed in accordance with Articles 10 and 11 of Directive 95/46/EC. This information shall be provided in writing, together with a copy of or a reference to the national decision giving rise to the alert, as referred to in Article 24(1).*

Comment: How does a passport holder receive an alert when there is no phone number, address or e-mail associated with passports?

Comment: it's a good question ... and belongs as a question somewhere

Comment: @user610620 The alert is to all Schengen nations (the authorities of one country enters an alert into the database so that it can be accessed by the authorities of other Schengen countries). It is an alert to other Schengen countries, not specifically an alert to the passport holder, though people are often informed in writing when an alert is entered about them. If you want to know what rights you have as a third-country national to ask for disclosure of any information stored about you in the Schengen Information System, that sounds like something to ask as a new question.

Comment: As a hint, I'd read [The Schengen Information System: A Guide for Exercising the Right of Access](https://edps.europa.eu/sites/edp/files/publication/16-11-07_sis_ii_guide_of_access_en.pdf).

Comment: Actually, I guess we have that question already: [What is the equivalent of a subject access request for the Schengen Information System (ie, SIS)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/159447/what-is-the-equivalent-of-a-subject-access-request-for-the-schengen-information)

Comment: @user610620 When the overstay procedure is started, you will be given a form informing you of the charges being made and contact information will be given togeather with the collection of your contact  information (address, e-mail etc.). Border control itsself does not impose a ban. Depending on jurisdiction, a state attorney will decide whether to procede and a judge will then make the final decision. It is a judge that authorises the **alert**. If you refuse to give the (or give faulty) contact information, then of course, you cannot be informed.

Comment: If a judge in a Schengen country makes a ruling on your case, and you have no idea that proceedings or a final judgment have been made against you, **are you allowed to contest the charges**, for example, **3 years later** when you realize, upon attempted re-entry, that such bans had been imposed on your person without your consent or knowledge, assuming that you had made the proper inquiries at the time to authorities as to your proper stay length, yet the judgment was passed with omissions of the faulty advice given that could have lightened your punishment had you been alerted abroad?

Comment: Need to be a bit careful here though. A passport does not necessarily demonstrate citizenship.

Comment: @user610620 That is question that should be asked at [Recently Active Questions - Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions), giving the **exact** jurisdiction with the **precise** reasons why you didn't give your contact information when the charges were made. Questions should be compleate and self contained. Comments should not be misused to ask further variants of the original question.

Comment: Plus, if a country cares about your ban, presumably they have an agreement with the banning country to share that information. For example, if the US is willing to deny you a visa over you having been banned from entering the UK, USCIS/USCBP might just send your information to UKVI.

Comment: See, this is the point of the question. You're the first one to say "USCIS/USCBP might just send your information to UKVI".

Comment: @user610620 you're wrong, moonman isn't the first to say that. This answer says "Some governments keep lists of violations, and some share those lists with other countries, but it's not universal. When they do share, the mechanism they share with is not your passport, but another form of communication."

Answer (score 2):

> Isn't that the point of passports? To contain data and violations on each traveler, and that data is shared between all countries who "access" or scan the passport to make a decision on whether to admit them or not?

The passport is just an identity document that has some stamps. A passport is not the right to enter a country.  That would be called "citizenship" :)

It's also not really a data port. It's not like a team of technologists led by Elon Musk did a from-scratch reboot of passports using 2018 tech. The whole world has to agree to basic technology changes.  It's been 2500 years of incremental improvements.

That said, each of the countries try to do their best with off-passport databases... and a few of them share data. EU obviously, but the Five Eyes and EU as well.

### You apply for a visa

> Thanks for the information, but there is still no resolution to the issue: How then does someone find out they are banned from a country before traveling, without attempting to cross that country's border?

You go ahead and apply for a visa to that country, in the normal fashion.  That's it.  They either grant you a visa or they do not.

"But I don't want to apply for a visa! My citizenship country has some sort of visa waiver with my destination country, and I'm able to do a visaless entry **normally**.  I want to know if I broke that by violating their rules."

### You already (should) know if you broke their rules

That's your answer. They usually publish their rules, so just compare "their rules" to "your behavior" and that should settle it.

"But I want to know if they FOUND OUT about it".  Okay LOL. I hate to say the answer is usually "yeah, they know".  But I gather you are not an immigration lawyer who specializes in that country, so you may not have ALL of your facts straight about whether *what you did* is the kind of thing they *ban you for*.  There are 3 ways to find out.

- Talk to an immigration lawyer who *does* specialize in that country.
- Attempt another visa waiver entry and *see what happens* but make room on your credit card, as you may be about to pay full price for a same-day return airfare.  Note that if a country does [preclearance](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/preclearance) at a given airport, use that route! That way you avoid a miserable and wasted double flight, and may even be able to salvage a respectable holiday getaway out of it.  (e.g. if in the EU going to USA, book through Shannon Ireland - make plans for both a USA holiday and a Shannon holiday.)
- (the surest, safest method) apply for a visa, as discussed.  That also gives you the best option to explain your case for why the previous transgression should be overlooked, since you have the opportunity for a written and organized statement with unlimited supporting docs, not the hostile chaos of an immigration desk at an airport.

Comment: If the country in question is a Schengen country, good luck getting them to entertain a visa application with a visa-exempt passport.

Comment: @phoog: Well, you can try to apply for a visa category that's outside the basic visa exemption.

Comment: _'A passport is not the right to enter a country. That would be called "citizenship"'_ is not quite true. A visa is also a [limited] right to enter a country, and has historically been placed into the passport (though it seems they're increasingly purely electronic but _tied_ to the passport).

Comment: @Auspex With a visa you're likely to get in, but you can still flub your entry interview or have an extenuating circumstance like COVID-19 happen or Trump's "ban 7 countries" thing happen, and still be turned away.  You call that a [limited] right, but I don't think it's a right if it's [limited] - then, it's just a privilege.

Comment: @phoog are you saying that if a visa-exempt national is refused entry to EU, then their only option is to keep trying to make visa-free entries and hope to clear it up at the immigration desk on landing?  That would be a very broken system.  Normally, "I was previously refused entry" makes applying for a visa reasonable - why is EU different?