# How can someone check if they are banned from the Schengen Area after an overstay?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, europe, legal, western-europe

Schengen countries in Europe keep little notes about foreign travelers in their Schengen Information System (SIS). Have no idea what that is, what it contains, or what it looks like.

Whether by this SIS or not by SIS, **how can someone check if they are banned from a Schengen country for an overstay after leaving the Schengen area?**

Is there a public way to check without a long-distance consultation or without testing the border guards? (Especially since the foreigner has already left the Schengen area and Schengen authorities have no way to contact or notify the foreigner because there is no e-mail, address or phone number associated with passports.)

Does the person's home country passport office have any way to check, possibly by scanning data transmitted to your passport by Schengen countries?

Additional info found in an answer to a [related question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158295/how-do-schengen-countries-know-if-someone-has-overstayed-internally):

> entries and exits from the entire Schengen area are not
> recorded in the SIS either (there is another system for that, which
> hasn't come online yet).

Comment: There is no "data transmitted to your passport". Passports do not hold any data other than what is printed and visible on them. See [Why doesn't my own country know if a foreign country has banned me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/179733/why-doesnt-my-own-country-know-if-a-foreign-country-has-banned-me) for more discussion on this point.

Comment: @GregHewgill Cannot is wrong, they can, it's just not used

Comment: @NicolasFormichella: Fair enough, corrected comment above.

Comment: @NicolasFormichella What data could they store onto a foreigner's passport if they chose to?

Comment: According to ICAO 9303 standard, quite a lot. The country that issued the passport could put in the exit restrictions, child custody info, or even full travel record. And (this is not yet in the standard *per se*, so decades from adoption), a foreign country could add e-visa or automated border clearance information to it

Comment: This data, such as full travel record, would be visible to any other country that then scans the passport?

Comment: I haven't read the standard further, but likely yes

Comment: @GregHewgill some passports do; for example they may hold fingerprints that aren't printed or visible.

Comment: I think the point is, RFID passwords (today) don't work any differently than paper-only (pre-RFID) passports. In a paper-only passport, there's nowhere to store data "in" the passport other than stamps or sometimes things physically stapled to the passport. Paper-only passports cannot "store" the fact that one has been banned from a country, other than by looking at entry and exit stamps. Which is exactly what an officer would do on entry - they inspect prior entry and exit stamps and decide whether to let you in or not.

Comment: That means, for example, that if you overstayed your visit to France (for example), then you may not be recorded as "banned" today in the SIS systems. But, if you try to visit a Schengen country tomorrow, the officer may look at your entry and exit stamps and THEN decide to deny you entry. So there might not even be any evidence of a "ban" today even if you did overstay.

Comment: Unfortunate to foreigners though is that there are cases where there is data about a foreigner's visit that is *not* contained in the passport stamps: If someone is waiting for Yes or No result on their residence permit application, for example, while staying as a tourist, they are legally allowed to remain until the permit decision is finalized even after 90 days. For example, if the foreigner leaves on day 110, one of the higher-up border guards will see in their computer that their residence permit application is "Still Processing" and will let them leave the country unharmed.

Comment: Upon return to another Schengen country, however (that may have no knowledge of the prior "Still Processing" situation in the other Schengen country that the traveler safely exited), are you saying they will dismiss the fact that they had a "Still Processing" during their last Schengen visit and exit, and still go by the passport stamps alone?

Comment: We have to make a distinction between stamps suggesting an overstay and a formal ban. If you have been banned, Schengen border guards would find out through an alert in the SIS and should deny entry without even looking at the stamps. The ban should be disputed with the country that issued it and border guards have very little discretion.

Comment: Now, if the stamps in your passport suggest you have stayed too long in the Schengen area (especially if it was actually legal as in @user610620's scenario but also if a stamp was simply forgotten) then the burden of proof is on you but the border guards still have to make a determination and decide whether they should refuse or deny entry or take further action. If the stampes are erroneous, the Schengen Borders Code even has a whole procedure to let them correct the record. I wouldn't rule out any outcome but it's not like they have to go by the stamps alone.

Comment: @user610620 Incidentally, some countries do give you a document (e.g. in France, it's called a *récépissé*) to cover such a waiting period. It's not quite a residence permit and doesn't always allow travel within the area but they are not relying solely on some national computer system to check your status.

Comment: @GregHewgill Incidentally, note that France doesn't routinely ban people merely for an overstay. Being denied entry doesn't mean you have been or will be banned.

Comment: *"Being denied entry doesn't mean you have been or will be banned"*. What does that mean? It's not coherent. Of course overstays are punished by France. A one-month ban still counts as a ban. Being denied entry definitely sounds like a ban. The idea here is to know that you will be denied entry beforehand.

Comment: @user610620 What makes you think that? There is nothing incoherent about it. Being denied entry just means you cannot enter right now. A ban means all border guards are legally required to deny entry for a specified time. Having been banned is but one justification for being denied entry (out of 9 listed in the Schengen area). A ban isn't a sanction either, it's an administrative measure to prevent a future issue.

Comment: In practice, there is no such thing as a one month ban, it's too much trouble for very little benefit. If you present enough of a risk to deserve a ban, it will be longer than one month. But that doesn't mean you will enter easily. If you have just overstayed, you're not entering the Schengen area for longer than that, if nothing else because of the 90/180 maximal stay rule. Border guards are also more likely to be suspicious of the purpose of your stay, at least if they have access to relevant information.

Comment: *" If you have just overstayed, you're not entering the Schengen area for longer than that"*. I don't understand this sentence, could you explain? And it's written everywhere that Schengen countries can impose (1-month, half-year, long-term) bans of varying lengths. If not 1-month though, what are they, the intervals?

Answer (score 3):

> Does the person's home country passport office have any way to check, possibly by scanning data transmitted to your passport by Schengen countries?

No. Countries do share immigration data, but they'll **never** do that

> Whether by this SIS or not by SIS, how can someone check if they are banned from a Schengen country for an overstay after leaving the Schengen area?

GDPR in the EU grants you the right to access, rectify, and delete your personal data, and SIS is not an exception :

From the [EU](https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/schengen-information-system/access-rights-and-data-protection_en)

> > What rights do people have regarding their data stored in SIS?
>
> If a person believes that their personal information has been misused,
> needs to be corrected or deleted, they may make use of the data
> protection rights recognised in the SIS legislation. These are:
>
> - the right to access personal data stored in SIS
> - the right to correct inaccurate personal data or have unlawfully stored personal data be erased
> - the right to bring proceedings before the courts or competent authorities to correct or erase personal data or to obtain
>   compensation for any damages resulting from breaches of data
>   protection law.
>
> The SIS legislation gives a person the right to initiate action before
> the competent authority, including a court, under national rules to
> obtain information, access, rectify, erase or obtain compensation (if
> the person suffers damages) in connection with an alert relating to
> him or her.
>
> Countries using SIS have mutually agreed to enforce final decisions
> handed down by the courts or authorities. This agreement means that a
> decision taken by a court or competent authority in one country should
> be recognised and enforced in all the countries that use SIS.
>
> **These rights can be exercised in any country that uses SIS.** The
> national procedures and contact points for access requests have been
> compiled in a [comprehensive guide](https://edps.europa.eu/sites/edp/files/publication/16-11-07_sis_ii_guide_of_access_en.pdf)

Follow the guide linked above

> for an overstay

Overstays are calculated from the passport stamps only, if an overstay had occurred, the guard checking you on exit would inform you of the situation as you'll may be detained, served paperwork, have your visa cancelled... or any combination of all that

Comment: Thanks. The "comprehensive guide" on how to check is outdated though because it contains United Kingdom, which is no longer a Schengen member. Could you correct the link? And how does your EU-centric answer change if we are talking about a non-EU Schengen member like Switzerland?

Comment: @user610620 the UK was never a Schengen member, though they did have access to SIS when they belonged to the EU.  Regardless. Nicolas Formichella has no more influence over the EU's publications than you do.  You can send them a message asking them to update the document.  The information in this answer applies equally to non-EU Schengen members.

Comment: @user610620 Since the **Schengen Information System** is an EU project, it is by nature 'EU-centric'. The last update was on the 2015-10-15. If you look for Switzerland in the document, you will find that information. [Guide for exercising the right of access | European Data Protection Supervisor](https://edps.europa.eu/data-protection/our-work/publications/scg-documents/guide-exercising-right-access_en)

Comment: @user610620 It should also be noted that the *SIS II* is not only about Schengen entry bans (which was not available to the UK), but also a major crime-fighting database (which was heavily used by the UK) and provides alert information for police, migration, justice and other authorities regarding missing people, criminal entities associated with crimes.

Comment: @user610620 Also. Switzerland has adopted a very similar law to GDPR (nLPD), and Norway, as a EEA member, is bound to the GDPR

Comment: The GDPR has a broad carveout for national security and the like (article 23) and in fact the SIS has provisions for alerts that should not be revealed to their subject, even alerts for discreet surveillance. Access is largely *ad hoc* and rooted in the SIS regulation itself rather than stemming from the GDPR. In fact, @user610620's remark is very interesting, the relationship between the Schengen *acquis* and the rest of EU law has always been a bit messy, Switzerland has to abide by it by virtue of having joined the Schengen area through a specific agreement, quite apart from the GDPR.